# Hibernate JPA: one table has one-to-many with more than 10 tables, and cause performance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

we have now, one basic table, T_RESOURCE, which contains the basic resource information, and some other tables which has relationship with T_RESOURCE, like T_RESOURCE_TAGS, which contains tags on resource in T_RESOURCE, a resource could have more than one tags, this is one kind of this table; there is another kind of this relationship, connected with a middle class, like T_FILES is connected with T_RESOURCE with T_RESOURCE_FILES, indeed T_RESOURCE_TAGS is also a middle table, but no table T_TAGS just like T_FILES. We totally have 11 relationships with these 2 kinds formats(or forms).
and we have a entity class for T_RESOURCE, in which all the related tables are connected with something like below:

```
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO)
@IndexedEmbedded(indexNullAs = Field.DEFAULT_NULL_TOKEN)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="T_RESOURCE_FILES",joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="RESOURCE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID") },inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="FILE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID", unique=true) })
private List<TFILE> files;  
@IndexedEmbedded(indexNullAs = Field.DEFAULT_NULL_TOKEN)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "T_RESOURCE_TAG", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "RESOURCE_ID"))
@Column(name = "tag")
private List<String> tags;
```

and we will get all the resource information in T_RESOURCE with all the resource ids(RESOURCE_ID) that fit for the user's search criteria. we got the results using a native query:

```
em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString(),TRESOUCE.class).setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(pageSize).getResultList();
```

the sql is something like

```
"select * from T_RESOURCE where id in ('1','2','3','4') order by ..."
```

It works in this way, but it cost much time to get tags from T_RESOURCE_TAGS, from T_RESOURCE_FILES, from the other 9 relationships, it works in way:

```
select * from T_RESOURCE_TAGS where asset_id = '1';
select * from T_RESOURCE_TAGS where asset_id = '2';
select * from T_RESOURCE_TAGS where asset_id = '3';
select * from T_RESOURCE_TAGS where asset_id = '4';
```

and in this way, we will find that more time cost if more resources are fit for the search criteria.

I also tried with join fetch, but seems there is limit on join fetch numbers, not work.
I also want to seperate these relationships from TRESOUCE class, and try to get them just like get TRESOURCE basic information. for information, for the middle table, there is no unique id for each record, only resouce_id with related id/or directly name for files, tags, etc.

Could you please give your ideas, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You an improve performance by using the annotation org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize on your collection.

```
@Column(name = "tag")
@BatchSize(size=20)
private List<String> tags;
```

will cause it to execute the following statement when loading the object:

```
select * from T_RESOURCE_TAGS where asset_id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4');
```

This will save several round trips to the database and speed up your application.

Comment: Thanks Terrence, it seems work when I add the annotation into TRESOURCE class, but not worked when I add it in the related entity class, like TTAGS

Comment: you haven't posted anything about your related entities, so I can't really speak to those.

Answer (score 0):

Some DB like Postgres has very useful array type. You can store tags without additional table inside one column. Hibernate supports mapping custom data types like arrays to Java objects. It can significantly improve performance.
But Oracle array is different case - you have to specify array length when creating table.

Comment: we use db2, and we'd better not change existed db2 tabls.